# Subset data frame based on date in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to subset my data frame based on the date. The structure of my data frame is as follows:

````html
```
str(db18)
'data.frame':   15790 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ Average.Distance                : num  5462 3093 5918 5752 1563 ...
 $ Total.HIR                       : num  1367 588 1881 1745 278 ...
 $ Velocity.Band.6.Average.Distance: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Date                            : Factor w/ 88 levels "1/2/18","1/3/18",..: 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 ...
 $ Week.Number                     : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Session.Type                    : Factor w/ 23 levels "Captain's Run",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Day                             : Factor w/ 6 levels "Friday","Monday",..: 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
 $ Season                          : int  2018 2018 2018 2018 2018 2018 2018 2018 2018 2018 ...
 $ Round                           : Factor w/ 23 levels "BYE","PM 1","PM 2",..: 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
#> Error: <text>:2:23: unexpected symbol
#> 1: str(db18)
#> 2: 'data.frame':   15790 obs.
#>                          ^
```
````

I wish to create a subset of my data from the `3/4/18` onwards. This is the code I have tried to run, which has bounced back with this warning message.

````html
```
db18 <- subset(db18,
+              Date >= "3/4/18")
Warning message:
In Ops.factor(Date, "3/4/18") : ‘>=’ not meaningful for factors
#> Error: <text>:3:9: unexpected symbol
#> 2: +              Date >= "3/4/18")
#> 3: Warning message
#>            ^
```
````

I understand I probably need to change the format of the date. How can I best achieve this and ultimately subset my data from the `3/4/18`?

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that your date column is a factor, which means that you can't directly use inequality operators against it.  One option here, while keeping your data frame structure the same, would be to convert the date column to a bona fide date, and then do the comparison:

```
date_comp <- as.Date("3/4/18", format="%d/%m/%y")
subset(db18, as.Date(db18$Date, format="%Y-%m-%d") >= date_comp)
```

Comment: Thank you @Tim. This was very helpful.